# Elasticsearch search in all fields inside a object

Tags: elasticsearch

Hello elasticsearch users,
Can someone help me with the following use-case scenerio.!

So let's say the index is "test_index", and type is "test_type".

The document has a similar structure.

```
{
    "first_name" : "test_FN",
    "last_name" : "test_LN",
    "details" : {
        "address" : "test_address",
        "address_1" : "test_address_1"
        "city" : "test_city",
        "pin_code" : "test_pin_code"
}
```

The mapping for the same would be something like :

```
{
  "test_index": {
    "mappings": {
      "test_type": {
        "properties": {
          "first_name": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "last_name": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "details": {
            "properties": {
              "address": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "address_1": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "city": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "pincode": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So, is it possible to find a specific keyword inside the "details" object?
I am aware about "_all" keyword. But it searches on entire document. However I'd like to restrict searching only inside specific nested field.

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch uses dot-notation, so if you want to search inside field `adress_1` inside `details` structure you should query `details.adress_1` field. I don't know what kind of search you need exactly, so I can't provide further help right now.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply,
I wanna do something like 
{wildcard: {
     "details" : "test_*" }}

Comment: So you don't know full name of field you're trying to check?

Comment: No i dont know the full path of the field.

Comment: Oh, okay. In this case i don't know how to help you (yet) maybe I'll find something

Comment: Well, I found its possible through query_string
But its quite slow. If there's a better solution available, I'd love to know.